# Why the functional test fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, controller

**Hello when run rake test:functionals, here's what I get on the shell :**

```
1) Failure:
test_should_create_client(ClientsControllerTest) [test/functional/clients_controller_test.rb:20]:
    "Client.count" didn't change by 1.
    <2> expected but was
    <1>.

    7 tests, 9 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors
    rake aborted!
    Command failed with status (1): [/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/...]
```

and this is what I have on line 20 in the clients_controller_test.rb file:

```
 test "should create client" do
    assert_difference('Client.count') do
      post :create, :client => @client.attributes
    end
```

**Please can anyone tell me where the problem comes from?**

*Thank you so much nathanvda!!!!*

I have pass the attributes to the test and it works.Here' the following code

```
  test "should create client" do
    assert_difference('Client.count') do
      post :create, :client => {:name => 'jeff', :adress => 'ter', :city => 'ny', 
                    :email =>'get@yahpp.fr', }
    end
    assert_redirected_to client_path(assigns(:client))
    assert_equal 'Client was successfully created.', flash[:notice]
  end
```

*Here's what I get after rake:test:functionals:*

```
Finished in 0.292246 seconds.

7 tests, 11 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, due to some validation error in the attributes you pass to the controller, there was no new client created.